# How do I create a desktop application for ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created a package and I want my end user to be able to use this package without having to type any command or even see a terminal.

How to do I create a desktop launcher file for Unity or GNOME?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226588/how-do-i-create-a-desktop-application-for-ros?/) by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1505 on 2016-02-14

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### **UPDATE**

Check this repository for a complete example including automatic desktop/icon file install :
https://gitlab.com/InstitutMaupertuis/ros_desktop_launcher_test

Read below if you want to manually create a desktop launcher.

---

First, create a directory for your icons, then copy the application icon to the directory:

[image: image description]

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/share/icons -p
sudo cp ros.png /usr/local/share/icons/
```

After that we need to create a `.desktop` file:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/share/applications/ -p
sudo gedit /usr/local/share/applications/ros_fanuc_m10ia_support.desktop
```

Make sure to have `ros-indigo-fanuc` package installed for this example:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Fanuc M10iA support
Comment=ROS - Fanuc M10iA support
Exec=bash -c "source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash && roslaunch fanuc_m10ia_support test_m10ia.launch"
Icon=/usr/local/share/icons/ros.png
Type=Application
Categories=ROS;
StartupNotify=true
```

Once this is done, use the Unity launcher and search for `fanuc`:
[image: image description]

Click to launch the application:
[image: image description]

You can also pin the application in the launch bar like any other application:
[image: image description]

Of course, this process would be ideally incorporated to the install target of your CMake script.
This way the launcher would be automatically created at the application installation.

---

Originally posted by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) with karma: 1505 on 2016-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12